# Some Capistrano deployment hooks not working

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am using `Capistrano v2.14.2` and trying to use the `before` and `after` hooks for `deploy:create_symlink`, but none of them seem to firing...

I was getting this Warning:

`[Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook 'deploy:create_symlink' instead of 'deploy:symlink'.`

So I updated my code to use `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`

Here is a snipplet of my `deploy.rb`

```
namespace :foo do
    task :start do
        puts "starting foo..."
    end

    task :stop do
        puts "stoping foo..."
    end
end

before('deploy:create_symlink', "foo:stop")
after('deploy:create_symlink', "foo:start")
```

Here is a snipplet of the output:

```
  * 2013-04-04 13:34:27 executing `deploy:symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /web/example.com/current && ln -s /web/example.com/releases/20130404203425 /web/example.com/current"
    servers: ["app1"]
    [app1] executing command
    command finished in 467ms
```

No hooks are called...

Hooks for `deploy:finalize_update` and `deploy:update_code` all seem to be working without any issue.

What has happened to being able to use `before` and `after` hooks for `deploy:create_symlink` ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm running into a similar issue, using the same version of Capistrano.  I'm also using capistrano-multistage, and I'm curious if that is causing the issue some how (haven't tested a plain Capistrano setup yet).

Basically, if you hook into a before/after trigger on deploy:symlink, it tells you to use deploy:create_symlink, but deploy:symlink is what actually runs.  If I trigger on either of those, it doesn't fire.

I ran across this article, which got me thinking that i should trigger on "after deploy" instead, since symlink is the last step in deploy for me:

[http://blog.rememberlenny.com/2013/03/04/deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-symlink-issue-fix/](http://web.archive.org/web/20130620001048/http://blog.rememberlenny.com/2013/03/04/deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-symlink-issue-fix/)

Here is how I resolved my deployment:

- Moved my "before deploy:symlink" trigger to "after deploy:finalize_update" (since that was the previous task and it actually triggers)
- Moved my "after deploy:symlink" trigger to "after deploy"

Answer (score 3):

change

```
"after deploy:symlink"
```

to

```
"after deploy"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Anyway as for April 2015 for Capistrano 3, commands like `before 'check:linked_files', :do_stg {}` work fine. One way to check what is (perhaps) working is to get the list of hooks with `bundle exec cap -T`.